# How to send undelivered email to a specific email address

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have method for sending email where I'm using MimeMessage from javax.mail. My application is sending some system emails where sender is fake email address (noreply@mydomain.com).
I need when some email will not be delivered to recipient it will be sent to support@mydomain.com.
I was searching in Stackoverflow but no answer helped me. Could someone help me?

Comment: I don't think you can do that on your side, only the mail server knows if mail is delivered or not

Comment: you need a connection to the mail server, hope this helps : http://cases.azoft.com/implementing-notifications-using-javamail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direct delivery reports to a specific address by setting the envelope return address.  Set the [`mail.smtp.from`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.from) Session property, or use the [SMTPMessage.setEnvelopeFrom](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.html#setEnvelopeFrom-java.lang.String-) method.

Note that not all delivery failures will result in a non-delivery report.  You may need to enable Delivery Status Notifications (refer to RFC 3462 and RFC 3464 for more information), but even then some servers won't support it or will ignore it.

See the [`mail.smtp.dsn.notify`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.dsn.notify) and [`mail.smtp.dsn.ret`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.dsn.ret) properties.

The [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#badaddr) has more information on this subject.